# Forking an app on heroku and setting different environment variables

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, fork

I'm in the process of setting up a staging environment for a current heroku app. I've successfully forked it so I have two apps running. If the names of the two apps are app_production and app_staging, how do I set environment variables for each one from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), you set config vars like so:

```
heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith
```

Since all Heroku commands support the `--app` switch, you do this for your production app:

```
heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith --app app_production
```

and use `--app app_staging` for your staging app.